# getting infinite loop in c# - calculator app beginner

Tags: c#, console, calculator

I am getting the infinite loop on my last while loop where it states: while (Valid3 == false)...
I expect to receive the console.writeline("invalid input please try again"), until the user satisfies the argument but instead when i enter an invalid input i receive infinite loop.  Though i feel the logic im using here is the same as the logic in the loops used beforehand.  Below is all my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculatorApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare my and then initialize to zero.
        float num1 = 0; float num2 = 0;

        // Display title as the C# console calculator app.

        Console.WriteLine("Console Calculator in C#\r");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------\n");

        // Ask the user to type the first number.
        //Console.WriteLine("Type a number, and then press Enter");


        Console.WriteLine("Type a number, and then press Enter");

        List<string> validChars = new List<string>() { "a", "s", "d", "m"};
        double negSqrt = Math.Sqrt(-1);
        bool Valid = false;
        bool Valid2 = false;
        bool Valid3 = false;
        float Number;
        while (Valid == false)
        {
            string Input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!float.TryParse(Input, out Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                Valid = true;
                num1 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input);
            }
        }

        // Ask the user to type the second number.
        Console.WriteLine("Type another number, and then press Enter");
        while (Valid2 == false)
        {
            string Input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!float.TryParse(Input2, out Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");

            }
            else
            {
                Valid2 = true;
                num2 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input2);
            }
        }

        // Ask the user to choose an option.
        Console.WriteLine("Choose an option from the following list:");
        Console.WriteLine("\ta - Add");
        Console.WriteLine("\ts - Subtract");
        Console.WriteLine("\tm - Multiply");
        Console.WriteLine("\td - Divide");
        Console.Write("Your option? ");
        string o = Console.ReadLine();
        while (Valid3 == false)
        {
            foreach (string s in validChars)
            {
                if (!o.Contains(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again");
                }
                else
                {
                    Valid3 = true;
                    switch (o)
                    {
                        case "a":
                            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} + {num2} = " + (num1 + num2));
                            break;
                        case "s":
                            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} - {num2} = " + (num1 - num2));
                            break;
                        case "m":
                            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} * {num2} = " + (num1 * num2));
                            break;
                        case "d":
                            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} / {num2} = " + (num1 / num2));
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
            // Use a switch statement to do the math.

            // Wait for the user to respond before closing.
            Console.Write("Press any key to close the Calculator console app...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading the input with string o = Console.ReadLine(); outside the loop!, put it after the while

Comment: Now is as good a time as any to familiarize yourself with the debugger.

Comment: Also, you don't need to be doing this weird Convert/cast stuff when you've just done a `TryParse`. You're doing extra work.

Comment: Your code is very convoluted. Drop the `validChars` variable and the last if-else statement and add a `default:` case to you switch statement instead. See: [switch (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Comment: thank you all lol!  I'm as newb as they get.  I should have debugged myself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read the operator inside the loop, otherwise you will always compare the same invalid input over and over. Also, you can simplify the test. Instead of testing against a list of valid inputs, simply add a default case to the switch statement. It will be executed if none of the other cases matches.

```
bool isOperatorValid;
do {
    isOperatorValid = true;
    switch (Console.ReadLine()) {
        case "a":
            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} + {num2} = " + (num1 + num2));
            break;
        case "s":
            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} - {num2} = " + (num1 - num2));
            break;
        case "m":
            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} * {num2} = " + (num1 * num2));
            break;
        case "d":
            Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} / {num2} = " + (num1 / num2));
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again");
            isOperatorValid = false;
            break;
    }
} while (!isOperatorValid);
```

`isOperatorValid` is much clearer than `Valid3`. I also used a do-while statement to be able to test the condition at the end of the loop, since we don't know its outcome when we start looping.

Comment: I used this!  I had to add isOperatorValid = true after every valid case to get it to work properly because if i entered an invalid response the value of isOperatorValid globally changes to false which messes up my do-while loop on retry.

Answer (score 1):

move your `Console.ReadLine()` inside your while loop

```
    while (Valid3) {
        string o = Console.ReadLine();
...
```

**Why does it do infinite loop**

You are asking for an input and after taking that input in, you go to your while loop. If the input was invalid, you are no longer asking for another input, instead, iterating over the same input again and again.